# Configurable Product Pages have multiple add to cart buttons

Tags: configurable-product, addtocart

My magento configurable products have two add to cart buttons, is there a way to delete one without interfering with my simple products add to cart button?

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label class="qty_label" for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?>:</label>
<div class="qty_pan">
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.add-to-cart .qty_pan").append('<div class="inc add">&#8250;</div><div class="dec add">&#8249;</div>');

    jQuery(".add").click(function() {
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
        var newVal = 0;

        if (jQueryadd.text() == "›") {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
          // AJAX save would go here
        } else {
          // Don't allow decrementing below zero
          if (oldValue > 1) {
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
              // AJAX save would go here
          }
          if(oldValue == 1){
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
              }
        }
        jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });


});

</script>
```

**Here's the view file**

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view row-fluid">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box span4">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="product-shop span8">
<div class="poduct_shop_padding">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>
<div class="review_email_con">
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
<div class="topprice_con">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
<div class="add_to_box_con">
<div class="qty_con">
            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box removeaddcart_con">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php /*if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif;*/ ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <!--<div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>-->
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="sku_stock_con">
<label><?php echo $this->__('Product code'); ?>:</label><span><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?></span>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?>:</h2>
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
<div class="add_to_cart_links_con">
<div class="add_to_cart_con">
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="add_to_links_con">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="share_con">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('view_share')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

        </div>
</div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I can't see the entire code for the page pasted here I can't comment much on it. But I can give you a pointer. Please put <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?> <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?> condition in your view.phtml file.

Comment: they disappeared and i got this error. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/ijolli/public_html/store/app/design/frontend/default/shoe_store/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml on line 72

Answer (score 1):

Nasir I was able to take it out once I came upon a page that list the info below. Thank you so much for all you've done!

Product view pages have a container that besides the "Add to Cart" button also shows the price, a field for the quantity, and "Add to Wishlist" and "Add to Compare" links. If you want to remove them all you can hide the container. To do that you have to edit the file bottom.phtml. The path to it for the default theme is public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml.

Comment out the following code:

```
<div class="product-options-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen in the default template. Could you provide the code of your catalog/product/view.phtml file?

Please replace your view.phtml file with the following code.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view row-fluid">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box span4">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="product-shop span8">
<div class="poduct_shop_padding">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>
<div class="review_email_con">
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
<div class="topprice_con">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
<div class="add_to_box_con">
<div class="qty_con">
            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box removeaddcart_con">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php /*if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif;*/ ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <!--<div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>-->
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="sku_stock_con">
<label><?php echo $this->__('Product code'); ?>:</label><span><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?></span>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?>:</h2>
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
<div class="add_to_cart_links_con">
<div class="add_to_cart_con">

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>

</div>
<div class="add_to_links_con">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="share_con">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('view_share')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

        </div>
</div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please don't forget to take a backup of this file.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and paste the whole code preformatted text block?

Comment: ok. thank you for explaining. Just posted code in question

Comment: ok i will try this and let you know. I see the entire code here when i click on edit my comment but not sure why it's not displaying. Thank you so much

Comment: this code has been taken from addtocart.phtml, please provide code for design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: ok just found it and pasted the code

Comment: Nasir, I think I'm lost on following how things work. I recieved notification to approve a couple of codes on here but i'm unsure if you revised them and i'm suppose to change them or if the approval was just for your to view them. please explain

Comment: This approval to view them only. But, the code you pasted is again the same as you already pasted previously and this code is taken from catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml not taken from catalog/product/view.phtml. This file contains more lines of codes

Comment: ok i apologize! i pasted over the copy.

Comment: Hi Dena, Did you try the code?

Comment: Oh no. It didn't work :( i believe same code. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/ijolli/public_html/store/app/design/frontend/default/shoe_store/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml on line 73